# How to use Chromebug to debug Thunderbird 9 extensions

Tags: thunderbird, chromebug

I'm running Thunderbird 9, trying to write my first extension. I've been to http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Chromebug_User_Guide which says that I need to install exactly the same version of Chromebug and Firebug.

The problem is, Chromebug stops at 1.8.0a2 and Firebug 1.8.0a2 isn't compatible with Thunderbird 9.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The only correct answer I can give you is "it doesn't work". Chromebug is geared towards Firefox and was only once made compatible with Thunderbird. For me personally even that version never worked.

As for alternatives, there is no really good alternative that will help. The only other existing tool is [Venkman](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Venkman), which at least used to work for debugging back in the days of Thunderbird 3.1. I don't think this tool is still actively developed though.

There are efforts to make the [Firefox Developer Tools](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/08/remote-debugging-on-firefox-for-android/) debugger work with Thunderbird. This option would make use of the remote support which is currently used for Android/Firefox OS. You would have to enable the debugging server inside Thunderbird and can then use the Firefox debugger to connect to Thunderbird. This option doesn't yet work, but stay tuned.